# std::transform and move semantics

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

I'm using Boost.Filesystem to create a listing of files in a directory. I use `boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` and `std::copy` to put each path into a std::vector as a `boost::filesystem::directory_entry` object. I wish to output to the file as std::strings though, so I did the following (\n to avoid the use of <<):

```
std::vector<boost::filesystem::directory_entry> buffer; //filled with paths
...
std::vector<std::string> buffer_native(buffer.size());
//transform directory_entry into std::string, and add a \n, so output is formatted without use of <<
std::transform(buffer.begin(),buffer.end(),buffer_native.begin(), [](boost::filesystem::directory_entry de)->std::string
    {
        std::string temp=de.path().string();
        temp+="\n";
        return temp;
    }
    buffer.clear();
    std::copy(buffer_native.begin(),buffer_native.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(out_file));
```

However the problem with this is it creates two vectors, the original of which is immediately cleared because it is not needed. This sounds like a perfect place for move semantics, but n3242 only provides the same two overloads of transform as in C++98. Is it possible to implement move semantics with `std::transform`? If it is not, would writing a custom loop be better?

I'm using GCC 4.5.2 (MinGW) on Windows XP.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This looks like a job for `make_move_iterator`:

```
std::transform(make_move_iterator(buffer.begin()),
                make_move_iterator(buffer.end()), buffer_native.begin(),
                [](boost::filesystem::directory_entry&& de) -> std::string
{
    // still makes copy :/ perhaps native() would work better, I don't know
    std::string temp = de.path().string();
    temp += "\n";

    return temp;
}
```

A move iterator is simply an iterator which moves its dereference result. Note that the class needs to support move semantics for this to even make a difference; I don't know if Boost FS does.

---

Note if your goal is to output them on separate lines, you're doing it wrong. Formatted printing shouldn't require the input data be in a certain format, that defeats the purpose. Adding newlines to your data just to format it to have newlines is nasty. It's handled for you by `ostream_iterator` anyway:

```
std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), //               vvvv
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(out_file, "\n"));
```

Anything more complex, make a lambda in for printing; don't modify your data beforehand.

Comment: just help compiler to either do RVO or move by returning unnamed temporary: `return de.path().string() + '\n';`

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea that something like `make_move_iterator` even existed (I haven't fully read n3242). I don't think that Boost.Filesystem supports move semantics yet, although I think they plan to in the future.

Comment: @mmoran: Yeah. You could just have the lambda argument be a reference to avoid copying.

Comment: @GMan I thought the `std::transform` functor needed a by-value argument?

Comment: According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), "unary_op and binary_op must not ... modify any elements of the ranges involved." I would think that moving from the input range would be considered modifying elements in it.

Comment: @SCFrench Isn't it only about the versions accepting execution policies?

Comment: @mentalmushroom The placement of the operation preconditions section on the page I linked to is confusing and make it look like they only apply to the versions accepting execution policies, but looking at the actual standard the preconditions don't say anything about only applying to ExecutionPolicy overloads. I'm going to leave a note on the cppreference page to see if it can be improved.