# Binary operator in std::transform with vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I am getting confused with standard library transform when applied to a vector of unique_ptr. I have defined a binary functor addScalar that take 2 const references to unique_ptr and return a const reference to a unique_ptr in order to avoid copying (that is forbidden with unique_ptr).

I then try to use it in a std::transform, but it seems impossible for unique_ptr do undergo binary operation at all, in spite of all my precautions to avoid unique_ptr copying...

Has anybody an idea of how to use std::transform with std::unique_ptr ? Or am I obliged to run through the vector with a for-loop and perform the addition "manually" ? I am also wondering if I could use `unique_ptr<const Scalar>` in my functor.

Here is my class :

```
#include "space.h"
#include "scalar.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

using std::vector;
using std::ostream;
using std::unique_ptr;

class addScalar
{
   public:
      unique_ptr<Scalar> const& operator()(unique_ptr<Scalar> const& scal1, unique_ptr<Scalar> const& scal2)
      {
         *scal1 += *scal2;
         return scal1;
      };
};

class Tensor4D
{
   public:
      Tensor4D(Space& space_in, int ncomp);
      Tensor4D(const Tensor4D& tens);
      Tensor4D& operator=(const Tensor4D& tens);
      size_t size() const {return comp.size();};
      ~Tensor4D();
   protected:
      Space* const space;
      vector<unique_ptr<Scalar>> comp;
   public:
      Tensor4D& operator+=(const Tensor4D& tens);
};
```

and here is the implementation of operator+= :

```
Tensor4D& Tensor4D::operator+=(const Tensor4D& tens)
{
   assert(comp.size() == tens.comp.size());
   transform(tens.comp.begin(), tens.comp.end(), comp.begin(), tens.comp.begin(), addScalar());
   return *this;
}
```

I get the following ugly compiler errors :

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_OIter std::transform(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _OIter, _BinaryOperation) [with _IIter1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<Scalar>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Scalar> > >; _IIter2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::unique_ptr<Scalar>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Scalar> > >; _OIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<Scalar>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Scalar> > >; _BinaryOperation = addScalar]’:
tensor4D.C:44:94:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4965:12: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘const std::unique_ptr<Scalar>’ and ‘const std::unique_ptr<Scalar>’)
  *__result = __binary_op(*__first1, *__first2);
        ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4965:12: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
             from /home/gmartinon/Kadath/C++/Include/scalar.h:27,
             from tensor4D.h:5,
             from tensor4D.C:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:190:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&&) [with _Tp = Scalar; _Dp = std::default_delete<Scalar>]
   operator=(unique_ptr&& __u) noexcept
   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:190:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::unique_ptr<Scalar>’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<Scalar>&&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:203:2: note: template<class _Up, class _Ep> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_convertible<typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::pointer, typename std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::_Pointer::type>, std::__not_<std::is_array<_Up> > >::value, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&>::type std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&&) [with _Up = _Up; _Ep = _Ep; _Tp = Scalar; _Dp = std::default_delete<Scalar>]
  operator=(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) noexcept
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:203:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
             from tensor4D.h:8,
             from tensor4D.C:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4965:12: note:   types ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>’ and ‘const std::unique_ptr<Scalar>’ have incompatible cv-qualifiers
  *__result = __binary_op(*__first1, *__first2);
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
             from /home/gmartinon/Kadath/C++/Include/scalar.h:27,
             from tensor4D.h:5,
             from tensor4D.C:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:211:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::nullptr_t) [with _Tp = Scalar; _Dp = std::default_delete<Scalar>; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]
       operator=(nullptr_t) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:211:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::unique_ptr<Scalar>’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:274:19: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Scalar; _Dp = std::default_delete<Scalar>] <near match>
   unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
               ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:274:19: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const std::unique_ptr<Scalar>*’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<Scalar>*’
```

Comment: You cannot copy unique pointers, so the copy assignment that's attempted by `std::transform` is not allowed.

Comment: Will `shared_ptr` do the job then ?

Comment: It probably would, but I get the feeling that this isn't appropriate to your problem. You don't really *mean* to share ownership. Start with a manual loop, and then see if any of it can be algorithmified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of addScalar will be assigned to a `unique_ptr<Scalar>` so it cannot return a const reference because `unique_ptr` has no copy assignment. So you will have to return by-value to invoke the move assignment.

To avoid constructing a new `Scalar` you could use a [`std:move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) to move into `addScalar` and then move assign to overwrite the moved from value:

```
class addScalar 
{
public:
    unique_ptr<Scalar> operator()(unique_ptr<Scalar> scal1,
                                  unique_ptr<Scalar> const& scal2) {
      *scal1 += *scal2;
      return scal1;
    };
};

Tensor4D& Tensor4D::operator+=(const Tensor4D& tens)
{
   assert(comp.size() == tens.comp.size());
   transform(make_move_iterator(comp.begin()), make_move_iterator(comp.end()),
               tens.comp.begin(), comp.begin(), addScalar());
   return *this;
}
```

Andrey makes a [good point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32916637/3422652), it is not clear if this is strictly allowed according to the standard. I'll leave that to a language lawyer. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247464/stdtransform-and-move-semantics).

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AxdfH1lqU0biVE2H)

Comment: Thank you very much it works well now ! I didn't know these move_iterators, so useful !

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard for `std::transform` says:

> binary_op must not invalidate any iterators, including the end
>   iterators, or modify any elements of the ranges involved.

The best way for you is to implement your own transform function for specific needs.